# No entiendo que falla en mi clase usando HttpServletRequest y HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

Luego de agregar unas lineas de codigo, no puedo ejecutar mi aplicacion en glassfish, no se que puede estar mal en las pocas lineas de codigo que edite, es la primera vez que trabajo con **HttpServletRequest** y **HttpServletResponse**

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import rptws.RptwsWebService;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 *
 * Llamado a servicios del RptGen.
 * 
 * 
 */

@WebService()
public class WSDigitalizacion extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WSDigitalizacion.class.getName());
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/sundadesa.hospitalitaliano.net_38084/rptws/RptwsWebService.wsdl")
    private RptwsWebService service;     
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param cAccion
     * @param iArea
     * @param iUsr
     * @param cParametrosXml
     * @param request 
     * @param response
     * 
     * @return Resultado de la llamada al RptWs.
     * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "callRptWS")
    public String callRptWS(@WebParam(name = "cAccion") String cAccion, 
                            @WebParam(name = "iArea") long iArea, 
                            @WebParam(name = "iUsr") long iUsr, 
                            @WebParam(name = "cParametrosXml") String cParametrosXml,
                            HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {  
        
            String result;
        try { // Call Web Service Operation
            String url_wsdl = utils.Utils.getUrlWsdlRptWs();
            service = new rptws.RptwsWebService(new URL(url_wsdl), new QName("http://rptws/", "RptwsWebService"));
            rptws.RptwsWeb port = service.getRptwsWebPort();
            result = port.rptGenWS(cAccion, iArea, iUsr, cParametrosXml);
            //System.out.println("Result = "+result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = ex.getMessage();
        }
        return result;
        
    }}
```

El código anterior era el siguiente.

```
 package ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import rptws.RptwsWebService;



/**
 *
 * Llamado a servicios del RptGen.
 * 
 * 
 */
@WebService()
public class WSDigitalizacion {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WSDigitalizacion.class.getName());
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/sundadesa.hospitalitaliano.net_38084/rptws/RptwsWebService.wsdl")
    private RptwsWebService service;     
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param cAccion
     * @param iArea
     * @param iUsr
     * @param cParametrosXml
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * @return Resultado de la llamada al RptWs.
     * 
     * 
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "callRptWS")
    public String callRptWS(@WebParam(name = "cAccion") String cAccion, 
                            @WebParam(name = "iArea") long iArea, 
                            @WebParam(name = "iUsr") long iUsr, 
                            @WebParam(name = "cParametrosXml") String cParametrosXml)   {  
        
            String result;
        try { // Call Web Service Operation
            String url_wsdl = utils.Utils.getUrlWsdlRptWs();
            service = new rptws.RptwsWebService(new URL(url_wsdl), new QName("http://rptws/", "RptwsWebService"));
            rptws.RptwsWeb port = service.getRptwsWebPort();
            result = port.rptGenWS(cAccion, iArea, iUsr, cParametrosXml);
            //System.out.println("Result = "+result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = ex.getMessage();
        }
        return result;
        
    }    

}
```

No se muy bien como trabajar con  **HttpServletRequest** y **HttpServletResponse** mi intención era securizar la función callRptWS() porque en este momento esta devolviendo información sin parámetros de seguridad.

Para desarrollar estoy usando JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Entre el problema no se puede utilizar HttpServletRequest y HttpServletResponse en un metodo SOAD.

Lo que se debe usar es la  Interface [WebServiceContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html)